# How to identify myself as someone's son/daughter?

Tags: words

I'm trying to make contact with one of my mother's old friends from some time ago, and I don't think she really knows or remembers me -- thus, I'd like to be able to identify myself as, say, Jane Doe's son or daughter.

I've searched all over the place and have found musuko/musume, but from what I'm understanding, it's what parents use to refer to their own (or other people's?) children. Would I be able to apply that term to myself as well?

Comment: Yes. "I'm John, Jane Doe's son" could be ドー・ジェーンの息子のジョンです。

Answer (score 2):

> from what I'm understanding, it's what parents use to refer to their own (or other people's?) children

No, musuko/musume does not have such a restriction. You can safely use musuko/musume when you say something like "I am a son/daughter of Jane Doe" or "Jane Doe had four sons/daughters."